# Forward network connection over ssh so that my outbound IP changes

Tags: ssh-tunnel

A service, for example an FTP server, only accepts connections from a specific network, where all users will have the same external IP-adress.

I want to connect to this service, but I'm currently not inside the allowed network.

I have ssh access to a server inside the network.

How do I use ssh to tunnel a certain port from my local machine, through a machine on the internal network, to the final service, so that any client opening the correct port won't notice any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a SSH tunnel to your specific network using the following command.
For instance, let's say you want to reach a web service on computer "mywebserver" (port 80).

- Under Linux or BSD, using OpenSSH, you can use the following commandline:

ssh -f mysshserver -L 1234:mywebserver:80 -N

- Under Windows, you can use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) which includes a simple graphical ssh tunnel builder

This will open a SSH tunnel between local port 1234 and remote webserver on port 80. You can then open your web browser and connect directly to your web server by typing "http://localhost:1234" in the address bar.

Comment: *Removed*, I completely missunderstood the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay. No, I can't get it working. Here's a shell script showing what I do:
`REMOTE_PORT=8080;
LOCAL_PORT=1234;
REMOTE_URL=somedomain.com;
ssh -f localhost -L ${LOCAL_PORT}:${REMOTE_URL}:${REMOTE_PORT} -N;
curl http://localhost:${LOCAL_PORT} | wc -l;
ssh ${REMOTE_URL} "curl http://localhost:${REMOTE_PORT}" | wc -l;`
I except the two `curl`s to give equal output, but the first one fails all together after a 60 second timeout, while the second one returns 29 rows. Running a local nmap shows ${LOCAL_PORT} as opened.

Comment: OK, the problem is that you wrote "ssh -f localhost [...]". You should change this and use "ssh -f my_ssh_server_that_is_inside_the_same_network_as_web_server [...]" instead. The rest of your command is OK.